# If f is differentiable then f inverse also??

Tags: analysis

If $f$ is differentiable (of course $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing or decreasing)
then is $f^{-1}$ (the inverse of f) also differentiable??

If it isn't find a counter example!

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: You should state how you attempted to solve the problem. This way people won't downvote your question.

Comment: to Arbuja. oh tnks consider your comment!

Answer (score 3):

Along those lines, any function for which the derivative at the point is 0 is differentiable but does not have a differentiable inverse (provided it has an inverse).

The standard example is $x^3$; its inverse has "infinite slope" at $x=0$.

Intuitively, this is because it can be shown that if $f$ does have a differentiable inverse, then

$$(f^{-1})'=\frac{1}{f'}$$

but if $f'=0$ this cannot work.

This problem is related in higher dimensions to the more general inverse function theorem (the "generalized derivative" needs to have non-zero derivative in order to have a differentiable "local inverse"), see for example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism

Comment: thanks to your precisely comment!

Comment: so..by inverse function theorm.  if f' is not 0 then f inverse is differentiable?

Comment: At least within a small enough open interval of the point in question

Comment: i agree.. i want find a example. about f' is not 0 however f inverse is not differentiable .  contrastly  f' is not 0 then f inverse is differentiable  example: y=kx, sinx etc..

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be the map $f(x)=x^2$. Now $f$ is clearly differentiable (and strictly increasing) but $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: however f(x)=x^2 in not differentiable at x=0

Comment: @EndofEternity: Sure it is. $f'(0)=0$.